# return value in function

Tags: c#, linq, function, return-value

I have 2 tables: `Customer` And `Customer_Address`

I have a function:

```
public IEnumerable<Customer_Address> ReadAddressForCustomer(int CustomerID)
{
    ProjectServiceForCustomerDataContext DB = new ProjectServiceForCustomerDataContext();
    var CA = (from C in DB.Customer_Addresses
              join cust in DB.Customers
              on C.CustomerID equals cust.ID
              where C.CustomerID == CustomerID
              select new
              {
                  CustomerName=cust.Name,
                  CustomerAddress=C.Address,
                  CustomerTel=C.Telephone
              }).ToList();
    return CA;
}
```

But the CA is not a `IEnumerable(Customer_Address)` because it has `Customer` field (`cust.Name`)

How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that @Daniel DiPaolo suggest is good one, in which he declares a light class to hold the only properties you want, but I think it is better to use properties rather than fields, as below :

```
class CustomerInfo   // new class
{
    public string CustomerName{get;set;}
    public string CustomerAddress{get;set;}
    public string CustomerTel{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You return an anonymous type, this is why it is not `IEnumerable<Customer_Address>`

Try using something similar to this

```
var CA = (from C in DB.Customer_Addresses
                  join cust in DB.Customers
                  on C.CustomerID equals cust.ID
                  where C.CustomerID == CustomerID
                  select new Customer_Address( // <--- HERE
                      cust.Name,
                      C.Address,
                      C.Telephone
                  ).ToList();
```

Comment: One would assume that `Customer_Address` doesn't have the fields he needs, which is why he's joining to `Customer`, no?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new concrete type that encapsulates the data you want:

```
class CustomerInfo   // new class
{
    private string CustomerName;
    private string CustomerAddress;
    private string CustomerTel;
}

public IEnumerable<CustomerInfo> ReadAddressForCustomer(int CustomerID)  //return new class
{
    ProjectServiceForCustomerDataContext DB = new ProjectServiceForCustomerDataContext();
    var CA =  from C in DB.Customer_Addresses
              join cust in DB.Customers
              on C.CustomerID equals cust.ID
              where C.CustomerID == CustomerID
              select new CustomerInfo    // instantiate new concrete type
              {
                  CustomerName=cust.Name,
                  CustomerAddress=C.Address,
                  CustomerTel=C.Telephone
              }   // don't call ToList anymore
    return CA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also cast it

```
Enumerable<CustomerInfo> CA =
                fruits.Cast<CustomerInfo>().(from C in DB.Customer_Addresses
                  join cust in DB.Customers
                  on C.CustomerID equals cust.ID
                  where C.CustomerID == CustomerID
                  select new
                  {
                      CustomerName=cust.Name,
                      CustomerAddress=C.Address,
                      CustomerTel=C.Telephone
                  }
                  );
return CA;
```